# Xuggler stream[0] is not video

Tags: java, netbeans, xuggler, xuggle

This is my first time asking question on this form . My question has 2 parts .

First please see the code below to extract audio from video File using Xuggle .

```
IMediaReader reader;
File f;
reader = ToolFactory.makeReader("E:\\NetBeanWorkspace\\Repo\\VideoSamples\\one.mp4");   
f  =  new File("E:\\NetBean Workspace\\Repo\\VideoSamples\\"+"one"+".wav");                 
IMediaWriter mediaWriter =ToolFactory.makeWriter(f.getAbsolutePath(), reader);    
int sampleRate = 44100;    
int channels = 2;    
mediaWriter.addAudioStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_WAV, channels, sampleRate);    
reader.addListener(mediaWriter);    
mediaWriter.setMaskLateStreamExceptions(true);

    while(  reader.readPacket() == null  );
```

1. I get following error on some files and some files work fine .

   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: stream[0] is not video
       at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeVideo(MediaWriter.java:754)
       at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeVideo(MediaWriter.java:783)
       at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.onVideoPicture(MediaWriter.java:1434)
       at com.xuggle.mediatool.AMediaToolMixin.onVideoPicture(AMediaToolMixin.java:166)
       at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.dispatchVideoPicture(MediaReader.java:610)
       at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.decodeVideo(MediaReader.java:519)
       at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket(MediaReader.java:475)
       at audioextractor.AudioExtractor.main(AudioExtractor.java:108)
2. What is the best codec for extracting 16 bit WAV file.

Please help me finding answer for these 2 questions .